# How to get audio element?

Tags: reactjs, html5-audio

Using React, I wish to get the audio element.

```
var AudioPlayer = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function () {
        console.info('Audio: component did mount');
        var audio = React.findDOMNode('audio');
        console.info('audio', audio);
    },
    render : function() {
        return (
            <audio src="/static/music/foo.mp3" controls />
        );
    }
});
```

But I keep receiving the error:

> Error: Invariant Violation: Element appears to be neither ReactComponent nor DOMNode (keys: 0,1,2,3,4)

Surely lowered components are React classes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works using the component references:

```
var AudioPlayer = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function () {
        console.info('[AudioPlayer] componentDidMount...');
        this.props.el = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.audio_tag);
        console.info('audio prop set', this.props.el);
    },
    render: function() {
        console.info('[AudioPlayer] render...');
        return (
            <audio ref="audio_tag" src="/static/music/foo.mp3" controls autoplay="true"/>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: React.findDOMNode is deprecated since React 0.14.0, use ReactDOM.findDOMNode instead