# With React, how can I keep a ref from being undefined/null?

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a simple music playing component. The idea is that you click on a button, and the track changes along with the descriptive text.

```
var React = require('react');

let rock = require('../images/pngs/rock.png');
let none = require('../images/pngs/none.png');
let blue = require('../images/pngs/blue.png');
let flash = require('../images/pngs/flash.png');
let estim = require('../images/pngs/estim.png');
let urban = require('../images/pngs/urban.png');
let intl = require('../images/pngs/intl.png');

export default class Radio extends React.Component {

   constructor (props) {
      super(props);

//The state that changes the info related to the tracks

      this.state = {
         audiosrc: "",
         station: "",
         name: "Radio",
         artist: "Off"
      }
   }

   //The ref is to get the audio element below, but its always null or undefined

   componentDidMount() {
     let radio = this.refs.playmusic;
   }

   //The click that enables the text to change

   handleClick = () => {
      this.setState({
         audiosrc: 'music/come.mp3',
         station: "Vice Rock Radio",
         name: "COME WITH ME",
         artist: "Puff Daddy & Jimmy Page"
      });

      radio.load();
      radio.play();
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <section className={this.props.radioClass}>

         <div className="septagon">
            <div className="labels">
               <p>
                  <em>{this.state.station}</em>
               </p>
               <p>{this.state.name}</p>
               <p>{this.state.artist}</p>
            </div>
            <span className="deg40" onClick={this.handleClick}
            ><img src={rock} alt="" /></span>
            <span className="deg90"><img src={none} alt="" /></span>
            <span className="deg140"><img src={blue} alt="" /></span>
            <span className="deg195"><img src={flash} alt="" /></span>
            <span className="deg245"><img src={estim} alt="" /></span>
            <span className="deg295"><img src={urban} alt="" /></span>
            <span className="deg345"><img src={intl} alt="" /></span>

            <audio id="playmusic" preload="none" ref="playmusic">
               <source type="audio/mpeg" src="" />
            </audio>
         </div>
      </section>
      )
   }
}
```

I've tried to create a selector to the audio element, but the element comes up null. I used componentDidMount, but the element comes up undefined unless I (for example) console log it inside componentDidMount. How can I set the audio element up to not be undefined or null when I use handleClick?

Comment: see, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31657335/how-to-get-audio-element. I guess you have to use `React.findDOMNode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to switch to the modern way of using refs (see [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs) for details). If we do so and refactor your code a bit like this:

```
class Radio extends React.Component 
{
   constructor (props) {
      super(props);

//The state that changes the info related to the tracks

      this.state = {
         audiosrc: "",
         station: "",
         name: "Radio",
         artist: "Off"
      }
   }

   //The ref is to get the audio element below, but its always null or undefined
   componentDidMount() 
   {
       console.log(this.playmusic);
   }

   //The click that enables the text to change
   handleClick() 
   {
        this.setState({
           audiosrc: 'music/come.mp3',
           station: "Vice Rock Radio",
           name: "COME WITH ME",
           artist: "Puff Daddy & Jimmy Page"
        });

        radio.load();
        radio.play();
   }

   render() 
   {     
     return (
         <section className={this.props.radioClass}>

         <div className="septagon">
            <div className="labels">
               <p>
                  <em>{this.state.station}</em>
               </p>
               <p>{this.state.name}</p>
               <p>{this.state.artist}</p>
            </div>
            <span className="deg40" onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
            ></span>

            <audio id="playmusic" preload="none" ref={(c) => this.playmusic = c}>
            </audio>
         </div>
      </section>
      )
   }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
ReactDOM.render(<Radio />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

It will work just fine and `this.playmusic` will contain reference to your audio instance, that you can access in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: So, in this case this.playmusic is just a name you assign to the element? And c is just a variable name like x or i?

Comment: `playmusic` will be local field of the `Radio` class. And yes `c` is just a arbitrary name of the parameter that is passed to `ref` function, its value we store in the `playmusic` field to access later on.